# Laravel 8 package development - Route Target class does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, routes, package, laravel-8

I know the title topic sounds similar to other questions, but I've searched many topics on stackoverflow and none resolve my issue.

I am currently developing a package under Laravel ^8.12, below the content of the function that register my routes:

```
protected function registerRoutes(): void
{
    Route::prefix('workflowmakr')
        ->namespace('AlvariumDigital\WorkflowMakr\Http\Controllers')
        ->as('workflowmakr.')
        ->middleware(config('workflowmakr.routes_middleware'))
        ->group(__DIR__ . '/../routes/api.php');
}
```

And below is the content of the `routes/api.php` file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::resource('actions', 'ActionController')->except(['created', 'edit']);
Route::resource('scenarios', 'ScenarioController')->except(['created', 'edit']);
Route::resource('statuses', 'StatusController')->except(['created', 'edit']);
Route::resource('transitions', 'TransitionController')->except(['created', 'edit']);
```

For a better view of the project architecture, below is a screenshot of the packages folder containing the package under development:

[image]

And finally, below is the composer.json declaring my package:

```
...
   "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "AlvariumDigital\\WorkflowMakr\\WorkflowMakrServiceProvider"
            ]
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/",

            "AlvariumDigital\\WorkflowMakr\\":  "packages/AlvariumDigital/WorkflowMakr/src/"
        }
    },
...
```

When I execute the command `php artisan route:list` to view all my routes I got this error :

```
$> php artisan route:list

   Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException 

  Target class [AlvariumDigital\WorkflowMakr\Http\Controllers\ActionController] does not exist.

  at D:\Films\R_D\Laravel packages\workflow-makr\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:832
    828▕
    829▕         try {
    830▕             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
    831▕         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
  ➜ 832▕             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
    833▕         }
    834▕
    835▕         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
    836▕         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is

  1   [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand::Illuminate\Foundation\Console\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))

  2   D:\Films\R_D\Laravel packages\workflow-makr\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:830
      ReflectionException::("Class AlvariumDigital\WorkflowMakr\Http\Controllers\ActionController does not exist")
```

**EDIT**

Below is the content of the `ActionController` file:

```
<?php

namespace AlvariumDigital\WorkflowMakr\Http\Controllers;

use AlvariumDigital\Models\Action;
use AlvariumDigital\WorkflowMakr\Helpers\Constants;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class ActionController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $query = Action::query();
        if (config('workflowmakr.pagination_size') == -1) {
            return response()->json($query->get(), 200);
        }
        return response()->json($query->paginate(config('workflowmakr.pagination_size')), 200);
    }

   // ...
}
```

**EDIT 2**

The content of the package `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "AlvariumDigital/WorkflowMakr",
    "description": "Generalize the management of your workflows",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Alvarium Digital",
            "email": "contact@alvariumdigital.com",
            "homepage": "http://www.alvariumdigital.com",
            "role": "Corporate"
        },
        {
            "name": "EL OUFIR Hatim",
            "email": "heloufir@alvariumdigital.com",
            "homepage": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/eloufirhatim/",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "support": {
        "email": "heloufir@alvariumdigital.com"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {}
}
```

Did I do something wrong or incomplete?
You can ask for more details if needed.

Thanks

Comment: what namespace is defined in that php file for that controller?

Comment: @lagbox thanks for your reply, I just added the content of the file on my post.

Comment: btw, `Route::resource` without 'create' and 'edit' is the same as `Route::apiResource`

Comment: @lagbox for `apiResource` good to know thank you

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autoload` after adding the namespace (psr4) entry to composer.json?

Comment: @Donkarnash Yes I did run `composer dump-autoload`, `php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan route:clear` to be more specific

Comment: the slashes in the namespace are a bit iffy ... is that the exact code in the service provider registering those routes? `AlvariumDigital/WorkflowMakr/Http/Controllers\ActionController` those should all be \

Comment: @lagbox yes I suspected that too, I already tried the /, \ and \\ but always the same error

Comment: if you remove the route definition for that resource do the rest of the routes get registered or will you end up with the same error for the next controller?

Comment: @lagbox just tried to remove the first route (linked to `ActionController`) and got the same error on the next controller `Target class [AlvariumDigital\WorkflowMakr\Http\Controllers\ScenarioController] does not exist.`

Comment: Just noticed that you are having a composer.json in your package as well - what's the psr4 entries in that? If you are structuring it as a separate package why not use composer path repositories to require the package in your app rather than just mapping the namespace

Comment: @Donkarnash I just added the package `composer.json` file content to my post as EDIT 2, but I don't understand your note **If you are structuring it as a separate package why not use composer path repositories to require the package in your app rather than just mapping the namespace**

Comment: Well you can have the psr4 entry in the composer.json of your package and then `"repositories": [ {"type": "path", "url":"packages/AlvariumDigital/WorkflowMakr"}]`in the composer.json of your app then run `composer require AlvariumDigital/WorkflowMakr` to require your package in the app. However as @lagbox has suggested your files should be in `src` if you are pointing the namespace to the src directory

Comment: @Donkarnash ok I see I will try your suggestion too, it makes more sense, and for **lagbox** solution, yes it did the trick :) thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have structured this directory incorrectly. You have the PSR4 autoloading loading the `src` directory as the namespace. Your controllers are not in the `src` folder, only the Service Provider is in there. So to composer there are no files for it to find and autoload based on your PSR4 autoloading.

Comment: THANK YOU, it works, I moved all my folders to be in the `src/` folder, and it's working, thanks again

Comment: @ELOUFIRHatim just saw your comment on my answer for the controller not found issue ... well, glad this all worked out then :-)